# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Xamarin Forms Picker

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using a picker in Xamarin Forms and I'm getting the selected value from picker if user choose it.

```
  if (loantype.Items[loantype.SelectedIndex] != null)
{
    //If user selects a value , code goes here
}
```

But if a user doesn't select a value from picker , it should be checked. I want to check whether it's null or not inside an object.

```
  AddNewTeam addnewteam = new AddNewTeam
         {

             first_name = firstname.Text,
             last_name = lastname.Text,
             email = email.Text,
             mobile = mobile.Text,


         };
```

But I'm getting

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

has been thrown error. I tried different solutions as well.

Could someone help me regarding this.

Comment: I'm sorry but isn't even valid code, so it's hard to help you with your problem this way.

Comment: What solutions have you tried already?

Comment: Please show your relevant code. The snippet you posted above does not help identifying your problem. Also it has a missing bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is a result from the index item being either greater than the size of the list/array, or negative. `Picker` doesn't have an event for when a value isn't selected, but it does have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event. For example:

```
<Picker
    ItemsSource="{Binding LoanTypesSelection}"
    SelectedIndexChanged="Handle_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

I have assigned an event to this `Picker` so that when the index does change, it will fire the `Handle_SelectedIndexChanged`, otherwise **nothing will happen/change**.

In the handler I have:

```
public string[] LoanTypesSelection => new string[]
{
    "Student Loan",
    "Mortgage"
};

void Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!(sender is Picker loantype))
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((loantype.SelectedIndex > LoanTypesSelection.Length) ||
        (loantype.SelectedIndex < 0))
    {
        // Display an error message?
        return;
    }

    MyLabel.Text = LoanTypesSelection[loantype.SelectedIndex]; // Or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if Count (or Length) property is equal to 0. Right now you are indexing empty array.

Answer (score 0):

When no value is selected on a Picker, its SelectedIndex will be -1. Accessing -1 on the IList is throwing the exception. Instead just check if `SelectedIndex` is valid or not

```
if(loantype.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    // do necessary actions
}
```

Comment: By inside object, do you mean inside ViewModel? Could you post your entire code or at least describe what you are trying to achieve. `loanType` and `AddNewTeam`  seems to be totally unrelated.